# Where does the cv.tree function get the data to perform cross validation from?

Tags: r, decision-tree, cross-validation

The lab in chapter 8 of ISLR contains the following exercise to cross-validate a classification tree:

```
library(tree) 
library(ISLR) 
attach(Carseats)
set.seed(2)
train=sample(1:nrow(Carseats), 200)
Carseats.test=Carseats [-train ,]
High.test=High[-train]
tree.carseats=tree(High∼.-Sales,Carseats,subset=train)
cv.carseats =cv.tree(tree.carseats ,FUN=prune.misclass)
```

Now, my question is: how does the cv.tree function perform cross-validation without the dataset being passed in as parameter, or is the training set referenced by the cv.tree object?

Many Thanks
Manu

Comment: would appreciate a comment if someone decides to downvote, such that i can improve my question, quite pointless otherwise, thanks

Comment: Well it wasn't my downvote but I can imagine someone might have seen this as asking the rest of us to do the work of first looking at the documentation carefuly, then (if not documented) looking at the code, deciphering it and then explaining it to you. It's not really a request to tackle a problem with code which is the main reason for SO's existence.

Comment: appreciate the response, but its actually been hours i have been trying to go through every reference tree.carseats has with no luck, the documentation of the package does not refer to the data set in any way (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tree/tree.pdf). thought an expert would be able to answer this in seconds.

Comment: I made a comment based on your statement that you wanted to improve the question. So far I see no edit. Apparently you found my comment less than useful. Since it's really not a coding question, but rather a statistical methods question, I will now vote for its migration to stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you did read the help and source for the function `cv.tree`, you would see it calls `model.frame` on the data, which is a function used to find the original data used to construct a model. See  `model.frame(tree.carseats)` and `?model.frame`. Presumably this works by parsing `tree.carseats$call`

Comment: I did not read the source until now - but i read the help and docs...sorry this comment just appeared once i submitted the answer- feel free to post this as an answer and ill accept it

Comment: No problem - keep yours. Might want to remove a couple of those surplus brackets in the answer though `eval(tree.carseats$call$data)` will do it.

Comment: Done - thank you jeremy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have been looking through the code as suggested by 42, and have found a call to model.frame(), which "returns a data.frame with the variables needed to use formula and any .... arguments". The tree implementation of this method (ignoring checks etc. does the following:

```
eval(tree.carseats$call$data)
```

Basically extracts a symbol with the name of the data set (in this case Carseats) and then evaluates on it.

Apologies if this was something obvious for others.

Manu